# connect HDPE pipe to copper

Tags: plumbing

Considering HDPE pipe for my 35' main service water line. Other options are PEX-a (more expensive, hard to find fittings) or PVC (cheap, but concerned [should I be?] for chemical leaching from solvent at ~4 connections). The water line transitions to copper above ground (shut-off valve, hose bib), then to new PEX-a in the crawlspace.

How do I connect 1" HDPE to 3/4" copper? A 1" compression union with sweat 1" x 3/4" reducer at the copper end? Can't find a consensus online.